# How do you scrape even numbered <TD> elements with python/selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Code that I am targeting looks like this:

```
<td>
     <b>Shipwreck</b>: Fairfax the Deckhand
     <br>
     <b>Harpoon Harry's</b>: Franchisco Corvallio<br>
</td>
```

The issue is there are 50  elements on the page, out of every 5 TD elements, I only need the second one. So for example  element 2, 7, 12, 17, etc. All of the  elements do not have any class elements or id's so the only way that I am able to target them is through order but I am not sure how to do that through selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be: `find_by_css_selector('td:nth-child(5n+2)')`